# Casting back query results stored in session for Custom Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, session, casting, authorization

I have the following table
[Permissions Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqqct.png)

On login, I am getting the values of ProductEdit, ProductView, ProductDelete for that logged in user and storing them in session to be used later for custom authorization on some actions within the project. This is achived with the following code (note var permissionJoin)

```
 if (usr != null)
        {
            Session["OperatorId"] = usr.OperatorId.ToString();
            Session["Username"] = usr.Username.ToString();
            Session["GroupId"] = usr.GroupId.ToString();

            var permissionsJoin = from up in db.UserPermissions
                                  join op in db.Operators
                                  on up.GroupId equals usr.GroupId
                                  select new UserPermissionData
                                  { UserGroupId = up.GroupId, P_Edit = up.ProductEdit, P_Create = up.ProductCreate, P_Delete = up.ProductDelete };

            Session["ProductPermission"] = permissionsJoin.ToList<UserPermissionData>();

            return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
        }
```

I am using a named class [UserPermissionData - that has the four properties I need] to store these values. The results are getting stored in the session fine. 
Now onto my authorization class were I need to extract those values and check - if the user has the permission for a particular. I have the following code

```
public class AuthorizeProductEdit : AuthorizeAttribute 
{      

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        //lets get the session values of the current user's permissions               
        var userP = (UserPermissionData)HttpContext.Current.Session["ProductPermission"];
        var editProduct = userP.P_Edit;           

        if (editProduct.ToString() == "Y")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

at the point of clicking an edit action for the logged in user I am getting an "Unable to cast object of type" error [see image]

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki4SB.png)

How can I cast back that query to be able to use if for checking my permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store in Session is a `List<UserPermissionData>` so you must cast session value to `List<UserPermissionData>`

```
var userP = HttpContext.Current.Session["ProductPermission"] as List<UserPermissionData>;

if (userP == null) return false;

return userP.Any(x => x.P_Edit.ToString() == "Y");
```